# How to correctly deal with duplicate transactions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, enhanced-ecommerce

Accidentally someone send 455 duplicate transactions to Google Analytics and i would like to fix it so my question is how?

I know of 2 methods:

- Refund -> Im not exactly sure of the consequences this have on the reports
- Send transaction with negative value -> I dont think this works as i expect since all it will do is add a new transaction with negative value but i ll be seeing 3 (1 original, 1 duplicate and 1 negative).

We are using Enhanced Ecommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that Google analytics is able to deduplicate identical transactions that were recorded in the same session (but I can't seem to find a resource that supports this). There are other methods you could deploy to add preventative measures like the ones in these resources:

https://www.thyngster.com/preventing-duplicate-transactions-in-universal-analytics-with-google-tag-manager/
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/pnmWOvHVk8s;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved using this docs: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en

Since im on the same day this worked perfectly.